# Xamarin IOS setDesiredConnectionLatency

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, latency

I need to set the connection latency on my BLE connection, but the documentation is very sparse on **setDesiredConnectionLatency**.

I use the CoreBluetooth framework for IOS, and the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheralManager.SetDesiredConnectionLatency/) simply refers to the actual method:

```
  [Foundation.Export("setDesiredConnectionLatency:forCentral:")]
  public virtual Void SetDesiredConnectionLatency (CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency latency, CBCentral connectedCentral)
```

I cannot see any examples, documentation or guides on how to use this, I have tried the following:

```
  var peripheralDelegate = new PeripheralManagerDelegate();
  //CBCentral central = new CBCentral();
  CBPeripheralManager peripheralManager = new CBPeripheralManager(peripheralDelegate, DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue);
  peripheralManager.SetDesiredConnectionLatency(CBPeripheralManagerConnectionLatency.Low, central);
```

I do not know how to either obtain a CBCentral instance, or how to create one.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to either use **SetDesiredConnectionLatency** or **CBCentral**

Comment: The link you have posted returns a 404

Comment: Fixed Documentation URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3.0, you can try to set the latency *after* having established a connection, since latency belongs to a peripheral-central **connection**, no to the peripheral itself (take a look to this link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393277-setdesiredconnectionlatency)

One way of ensuring that you already have a connection (but that only works if you have characteristics in your peripheral to which the central can suscribe) is by implementing the `didSubscribe` callback in your `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` class:

```
public func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    peripheralManager?.setDesiredConnectionLatency(.low, for: central)
}
```